# Complex Analysis-Prove f(z)=g(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Suppose $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are two holomorphic functions in the unit disk $D=z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1$ such that $(i)f(0)=g(0)$ and $(ii)$ the equality $$e^{f(z)}=e^{g(z)}$$ holds for every $z\in D$. prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ for every $z\in D$.

This is what i have so for:

Let, $F=f(z)-g(z)$

then, $e^{F(z)}=e^{f(z)}-e^{g(z)}=e^{f(z)-g(z)}=e^{0}=1$

I know i am supposed to use the Cauchy Reimen equaitions, but i can't figure out the next steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(z) = f(z) - g(z)$ satisfies
$$
 e^{F(z)} = e^{f(z)-g(z)} = \frac{e^{f(z)}}{e^{g(z)}} = 1
$$
for all $z \in D$, therefore the derivative vanishes:
$$
 0 = \left(  e^{F(z)} \right)' = F'(z)  e^{F(z)} \, .
$$
The exponential function has no zeros, so $F'(z)=0$ in $D$, which 
means that $F = f-g$ is constant:
$$
 f(z) - g(z) = f(0) - g(0) = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: i get why f-g is constant. but how is it zero? how is f(z)-g(z)=f(0)-g(0)

Comment: @HAC: Because you *assumed* that $f(0)=g(0)$, that is your condition (i).

Comment: i know f(0)=g(0). but does tht make f(z)-g(z)= f(0)-g(0)

Comment: @HAC: $F = f-g$ is constant, therefore $F(z) = F(0) $ for all $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f-g$ is a holomorphic function with value in $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$. If $f-g$ is non-constant, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) its image is an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $f-g\equiv f(0)-g(0)=0$. Whence the result.

It is a bit overkill to use the open mapping theorem as your result hold for continuous functions; indeed, one can notice that the image of $f-g$ must be connected from the intermediate value theorem and since $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is disconnected, then $f-g$ is constant.

Comment: i havent studied the open mapping theorem. is there a way to do this using the cauchy reimen equations

Comment: Even better, use the intermediate value theorem which you have almost surely studied before.

Comment: what do you mean by "the image of f - g must be connected"? i have studied intermediate value theorem in calculus, but how do i apply it here

Comment: The disk $D$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, hence $(f-g)(D)$ is connected, the intermediate value theorem states that the continuous image of a connected set is still connected.

Comment: but how does that prove f(z)=g(z) ?

Comment: You know that $(f-g)(D)$ is connected and contained in $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$, so it is a point.